# Sorting An Array of Pairs By The First Value in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a simple pair class and have created an array of them.

```
private static class Pair
{
    private String l;
    private String e;
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to sort an array of pairs such as: 
`(a, de), (g, e), (dde, gh)`
by just first element in the pair. Creating a result of: `(a, de), (dde, gh), (g,e)` I know this is possible in c++, but I'm new to Java and have been searching online for hours for a solution. I've read that you can use Comparator, but am still not sure how that really works. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an inline custom comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(pairArray, new Comparator<Pair>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Pair p1, Pair p2) {
       return p1.getL().compareTo(p2.getL());
   }
});
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain the a1.getL().compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getL()); part? What does getL do and do I have to put the compareToIgnoreCase if I know it will always start with a capital letter?

Comment: `getL()` is what you have to implement in `Pair`. Since fields `l` and `r` are private, you need getters for them. Usually, it is a public method that just returns the value of `l`.

Comment: Okay, how come I need to put Object a1 and Object a2? Sorry if it's a dumb question. This is literally my first Java program.

Comment: A sorting algorithm performs a lot of comparisons between pairs of sorted objects (pairs of `Pair`s in your case). Each time when this algorithm needs a comparison, it calls `compare` provided by you giving it two objects that need to be compared. These two objects are arguments of `compare` and named `a1` and `a2` in this example. You do not need to set them explicitly, your responsibility is to define the required ordering in terms of them.

Comment: Making a `List` out of the given array is absolutely unnecessary for the purpose of sorting. It increases the memory consumption and moreover, it leaves the initial array unsorted.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach would be:

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<Pair>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pair p1, Pair p2) {
        return p1.l.compareTo(p2.l);
    }
});
```

Java 8 makes it simpler with lambdas:

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, (p1, p2) -> p1.l.compareTo(p2.l));
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the `l` field is publicly accessible, which, even if it is in the OP, should not be.

Comment: I totally agree that the pure OOP approach requires hiding internals of the class and it would be more idiomatic to introduce getters and use them. In this particular example, however, it's obvious that `Pair` is a nested class (it's defined as `private static`), so its safe to assume that the caller has access to its private fields, otherwise it wouldn't have been able to even instantiate `Pair`s.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tim Biegeleisen's answer, there is one more option: make `Pair` implement `Comparable` interface:

```
private static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>
{
    private String l;
    private String e;

    int compareTo(Pair that) {
        return this.l.compareTo(that.l);
    }
}

List<Pair> pairList;
Collections.sort(pairList);
```

The choice between these two options depends on whether you want to modify `Pair` (`Comparable` requires it, `Comparator` does not), and whether you can have different possible orderings (`Comparable` allows to use only one ordering, `Comparator` allows to define as many orderings as you wish). Of course, you can also combine the approaches and implement default ordering in implementation of `Comparable` interface, but use also additional orderings with `Comparator`.

Comment: Upvoted.  One possible drawback of overriding `compareTo` is that there is only one such method.  If you had the need to sort `Pair` in different ways, custom comparators allow you to do this.  And any number of comparators can be defined.